# lvalue required as left operand of assignment when returning a pointer to a private member variable

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to make a Linked List with an iterator class. I want to set the node in the iterator class to the head of the linked list. Basically, to be able to type something like:

```
iterator it;
it.currentHead = head;
```

This works if `currentHead` is public, however since it's private, I add a function in the `iterator` class to return it instead, but it causes an error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T value;
    Node* next;
};

template<class T>
class myList
{
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    int size;
public:
    class iterator {
    private:
        Node<T>* currentNode;
    public:
        iterator(){
            currentNode = NULL;
        }
        Node<T>* returnCurrent(){
            return currentNode;
        }
    };

    myList(){
        head = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    myList(T value, int initial_size){
        size=initial_size;
        head = new Node<T>();
        head->value = value;
        head->next = NULL;

        if(size>1){
            Node<T>* currentNode = head;
            for(int i=1;i<size;i++){
                Node<T>* nextNode = new Node<T>();
                currentNode->next = nextNode;
                nextNode->value=value;
                nextNode->next=NULL;
                currentNode = nextNode;
            }
        }
    }

    ~myList(){
        Node<T>* currentNode = head;
        Node<T>* prev = NULL;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            if(currentNode->next!=NULL){
                prev=currentNode;
                currentNode=currentNode->next;
                delete prev;
            }
        }
    }

    iterator begin(){
        iterator it;
        it.returnCurrent()=head;
        return it;
    }

};

int main()
{
    myList<int> list(5,3);
    myList<int>::iterator it = list.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After friending `myList` to `iterator`, make a private user-defined iterator ctor that accepts the starting head. That makes the `myList::begin()` method `return iterator(head);`

Comment: In writing `it.returnCurrent()=head;`, you're trying to do an assignment on an rvalue (prvalue actually). It's like writing `0xdeadbeef = 1;` which doesn't make sense. If you want to do assignment through `returnCurrent()` (which I don't recommend personally), it needs to return a "reference to pointer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`returnCurrent()` returns `currentNode` *by value*, so even if you could assign a new value to the returned pointer (which you can't), it would not update `currentNode`. For that, `returnCurrent()` would need to return `currentNode` *by reference* instead, eg:

```
Node<T>*& returnCurrent() { return currentNode; }
```

Then `it.returnCurrent()=head;` will work.

Alternatively, you can return `currentNode` *by pointer* instead, eg:

```
Node<T>** returnCurrent() { return &currentNode; }
...
*(it.returnCurrent())=head;
```

However, a better option is to get rid of `returnCurrent()` altogether, and instead pass the desired `Node*` to the `iterator` constructor, eg:

```
class iterator {
private:
    Node<T>* currentNode;
public:
    iterator(Node<T>* n){
        currentNode = n;
    }
};

iterator begin(){
    return iterator(head);
}
```